# static_pointer_cast<Derived> pReallyABase = static_pointer_cast<Derived>(pBase) works! Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, downcast

I don't understand why this works.
pReallyABase is a downcasted shared_pointer< Derived > which points to a base class instance.

I understand why the compiler lets me call pReallyABase->onlyForDerived() since I defined it as a derived class pointer, but why don't I get a runtime error when I try to invoke a derived class function using that pointer?

```
class Base { 
    public:
        virtual string whatAmI() {
            return "I am a Base";
        }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        virtual string whatAmI() {
            return "I am a Derived";
        }

        string onlyForDerived() {
            return "I can do Derived things";
        }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    shared_ptr<Base> pBase = shared_ptr<Base>(new Base);
    shared_ptr<Derived> pReallyABase = static_pointer_cast<Derived>(pBase);

    cout << pReallyABase->whatAmI() << endl;
    cout << pReallyABase->onlyForDerived() << endl;  //Why does this work?
    return 0;
}
```

#### Results

```
I am a Base
I can do Derived things
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour means what it says.

Comment: Try making `onlyForDerived` read or write a `Derived` member and you'll likely not have such luck :)

Answer (score 2):

This regards how the member function(non static and non virtual) is called in C++, the book "Inside C++ object model" has an explain on this:

One C++ design criterion is that a nonstatic member function at minimum must be as
efficient as its analogous nonmember function. There should be no additional overhead
for choosing the member function instance. This is achieved by internally transforming
the member instance into the equivalent nonmember instance. After these transformations
each of its invocations must also be transformed: For example:

```
obj.magnitude();
```

becomes

```
magnitude_7Point3dFv(&obj);
```

and

```
ptr->magnitude();
```

becomes

```
magnitude_7Point3dFv(ptr);
```

So as the example above, the function onlyForDerived doesn't use any  member variables of the class  Derived, so it works. But this is an undefined behavior, we should not depend on it.

Comment: it seems to compile even if you define `int x=0` in `Derived` then increment it in `onlyForDerived`.

Comment: You should probably mention that this is the reason why it's likely to work on some implementations, but that the behaviour is undefined so anything could happen.

Comment: @BenHymers, you're right

Comment: @vsoftco, is the program running in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: Make the member virtual and even without accessing member vars, it will still likely exhibit a crash (on any reasonable compiler, anyway). The code generated for virtual vs. non-virtual method calls will be very telling in a disassembly of the presented code.

Comment: @BenHymers yes indeed, even if it seem to work, if you try to initialize `x` in a constructor then increment it, you're out of luck. `x` will not be initialized by the constructor, however the code continues to compile under `g++`.

Comment: @Matt I'm compiling with `g++` from command line with no optimizations turned on by default, so it is not release but not debug either, since I don't use `-g` flag.

Comment: @vsoftco, in VS2010, it just crashes as this kind behavior lead to memory corruption.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, so anything can happen :)

Answer (score 2):

You're automatically getting undefined behavior by treating a `Base` object as a `Derived` so *any* behavior you see is legitimate.

In this case, since the compiler "knows" that the static type of the derived pointer is `Derived`, it's able to make the call to the function even though it's not legal to do so.

It doesn't raise a runtime error because it doesn't have to (undefined is undefined). That said, if the function were virtual it would probably crash in most implementations, and if the derived class had data that the derived function referred to it would probably either crash or generate unexpected outputs.